# Odd InvalidCastException

Tags: wpf, vb.net

I'm getting an odd invalid cast exception, which I suspect is due to mismatched namespaces, but I'm not sure where.

The exception message is:

Additional information: Unable to cast object of type 'FishTracker.FishTracker' to type 'FishTracker.Application'.

Now this has come about because I decided to rebuild an application from the ground up having spotted a crucial flaw.  It's a wpf app.

The main xaml reads like this:

```
<Application x:Class="FishTracker"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:FishTracker"
StartupUri="Views\MainRibbonView.xaml">
<Application.Resources>

</Application.Resources>
```

In the vb file behind that is defined thus:

```
Public Partial Class FishTracker
Inherits Windows.Application
```

and in the application settings the Assembley name is FishTracker and the RootNamespace is FishTracker.

As far as I can see everything matches, it builds yet fails when it runs with the invalidcast exception thrown from  MyWpfExtension.vb (and I can't even see that in the solution) .

Any ideas most welcome.

Comment: MyWpfExtenstion is a normally hidden file. In the Solution Explorer, highlight your project node and then choose to view all files. The file should be visible under the "My Project" node. The issue might be that the designer is expecting that the thing that inherits from Windows.Application is a class named Application and not FishTracker.

Comment: @MartinSoles  Thanks for your input.. it turns out that the cause of this was a reference that I was making to My.Application which it no longer likes.  Not sure why this should be the case but at least now I know what the cause was.